# Result of conflicting GIT branches merged at the same time

Tags: git, merge

For the most part, my question was fully asked and answered here: [Git Merging - what happens to 2 branches being merged at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773595/git-merging-what-happens-to-2-branches-being-merged-at-same-time)
The small part that I'm curious about is what would happen in that scenario to Bob's code. At the point where he can't merge his changes because Alice got in there first so that now his local Master branch is out of sync with the origin branch, he is forced to do a pull or fetch to bring his local branch back into line with the origin/master. What happens to his locally committed changes? Surely, if he pulls again from the master, aren't his changes now overwritten locally?

[EDIT]
I could have worded that a lot better. I think where I'm looking for clarity is that in the scenario linked, both users working on the same file, Bob makes a change to line 2 of a file. Alice also makes a change to line 2 in her branch. Alice gets her merge in first. Bob commits all his changes locally & tries to merge his changes to the origin/master. It fails as the origin/master has changed so he is forced to pull from the origin/master again. Once he does, his local master copy has Alice's changes in it. He's now forced to commit again to commit his changes to his new local master then he can do a merge back to the origin/master.

Have I understood that correctly?

Comment: No. Why would the changes be overwritten? A merge is creating a new commit, it doesn't ever delete/suppress/modify *anything* from the commit tree, it only adds to it.

Answer (score 0):

> At the point where he can't merge his changes because Alice got in there first ...

That's where your question goes wrong.  He *can* merge because he does not yet have Alice's merge.  What he cannot do successfully—because Alice beats him to the punch—is `git push` his merge to the other Git.

Having failed the `git push`, Bob must step back and run `git fetch`.  Now Bob has (and must observe) Alice's merge.  If Bob chooses to step all over everything, he can, in *his* repository, override Alice's merge—Bob's repository is Bob's, after all, to do with as Bob would like—but if he uses the default mechanisms that Git provides for sharing work, he will:

- rebase his commits to come after Alice's merge (discarding his merge in the process), or
- discard his current merge (this is a tiny bit tricky, but Bob can use `git rebase -i` to do it easily) and then re-merge with Alice's merge, or
- the simplest method: merge his merge with Alice's merge.

All three methods tend to succeed automatically, or have conflicts in which Bob is probably the person best equipped to figure out the correct resolution.  The result is something that Bob can now `git push` successfully, without using `--force`.

Let's consider all three cases again:

1. Rebase on Alice's merge.

   Here, Bob chooses to replace his old series of commits (that come in parallel with Alice's work) with new-and-improved rebased commits (that come after Alice's work).  Since they start with Alice's modified code base, they keep Alice's changes.
2. Discard current merge (`MB`) entirely, leaving his in-parallel-with-Alice series of commits but no merge commit at the end.

   Here, Bob merges his series of commits with Alice's merge result.  Since her merge result has her code incorporated, Bob's merge result has Alice's code incorporated as well, unless Bob removes it for some reason.
3. Merge with Alice's merge.

   Here, Bob keeps `MB` (from the linked Q&A) but adds a *new* merge that merges `MB` with `MA`.  This combines Alice's changes with Bob's changes, so it has Alice's work incorporated in its final result.

The difference between these three options lies in the final graph and set-of-commits: how hard is it to read these (the commits and the graph, both), how hard is it to use in the future to zero in any introduced bugs, and so on.  There are arguments for all three processes, and arguments against all three.  Alice and Bob should agree to whatever procedure they use, but that agreement is not part of the tools that Git provides.

Comment: Thanks for putting time in to explain. Your comment - "Having failed the git push, Bob must step back and run git fetch. Now Bob has (and must observe) Alice's merge. If Bob chooses to step all over everything, he can, in his repository, override Alice's merge—Bob's repository is Bob's, after all". 
This is what I was getting at. In this instance, its a last write wins if Bob decides that he doesn't like Alice's change to line 2 and just overwrites it with his, commits then pushes back to the Master.

Comment: Bob only overwrites someone else's work if Bob is a (insert derogatory adjective here). Git doesn't do that by default: you have to force it to do that. Don't be a (whatever adjective). Note that Git can't stop Bob from doing that even if his changes *don't* overlap Alice's; Git just gives Bob a conflict when his change *do* overlap.